# Magento 2 USPS shipping method estimated date and time

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, usps

I need to show estimated date and time with shipping method name. I am trying USPS api to get estimated date and time but facing some error. Below the api which i am trying and the error.

https://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=SDCGetLocations&XML=05510755428

https://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=PriorityMail&XML=5510755428

Array
(
[Number] => 80040B19
[Description] => XML Syntax Error: Please check the XML request to see if it can be parsed.(B)
[Source] => USPSCOM::DoAuth
)

If anyone can help with this then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For the delivery date and time, you need to use 'RateTimeInTransit' in the 'RequestOption'. By filling the appropriate details , you will get an array which will have a field 'timeintransit'. You can fetch the required information from there. Please check : https://prnt.sc/tjkkti.

```
    $data ="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>  
<AccessRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">  
    <AccessLicenseNumber>$this->AccessLicenseNumber</AccessLicenseNumber>  
    <UserId>$this->UserID</UserId>  
    <Password>$this->Password</Password>  
</AccessRequest>  
<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>  
<RatingServiceSelectionRequest xml:lang=\"en-US\">  
    <Request>
      <RequestAction>Rate</RequestAction>  
      <RequestOption>RateTimeInTransit</RequestOption>  
    </Request>
<Shipment>  
    <NumOfPieces>33</NumOfPieces>
    <Shipper>  
      <ShipperNumber>$this->shipperNumber</ShipperNumber>  
      <Address>  
        <AddressLine1>$this->ShipperAddressLine1</AddressLine1>  
        <City>$this->ShipperCity</City>  
        <PostalCode>$this->ShipperPostalCode</PostalCode>  
        <CountryCode>$this->ShipperCountryCode</CountryCode>  
      </Address>  
    </Shipper>  
    <ShipTo>  
      <CompanyName></CompanyName>
      <Address>  
        <AddressLine1>$toAddressLine1</AddressLine1>
        <City>$toCity</City>
        <PostalCode>$toZip</PostalCode>  
        <CountryCode>$toCountry</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipTo>  
   <ShipFrom>  
      <CompanyName></CompanyName>
      <Address>  
        <AddressLine1>$fromAddressLine1</AddressLine1>
        <City>$fromCity</City>
        <PostalCode>$fromZip</PostalCode>  
        <CountryCode>$fromCountry</CountryCode>
      </Address>
    </ShipFrom>         
    <Service>  
      <Code>$service</Code>  
      <Description>$serviceDesc</Description>  
    </Service>  
    <Package>  
      <PackagingType>  
        <Code>$packageTypeCode</Code>  
      </PackagingType>  
      <PackageWeight>  
        <UnitOfMeasurement>  
          <Code>$this->weightUnits</Code>  
        </UnitOfMeasurement>  
        <Weight>$weight</Weight>  
      </PackageWeight>  
      <Dimensions>  
        <UnitOfMeasurement>  
          <Code>$this->dimensionsUnits</Code>  
        </UnitOfMeasurement>  
          <Length>$length</Length>  
          <Width>$width</Width>  
          <Height>$height</Height>  
      </Dimensions>  
    </Package>  
<DeliveryTimeInformation>
  <PackageBillType>03</PackageBillType>
  <Pickup>
    <Date>$today</Date>
  </Pickup>
</DeliveryTimeInformation>
</Shipment>  
</RatingServiceSelectionRequest>";  
$ch = curl_init("https://www.ups.com/ups.app/xml/Rate");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);  
$result=curl_exec ($ch);  
$data = strstr($result, '<?');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I need it for USPS shipping methods. Not for ups shipping methods. Looks like you have provided answer for ups shipping method.